# Gebruks on Achron Shel Pesach

Tags: passover, food, eretz-yisrael

Those that refrain from Gebruks often eat Gebruks on Achron Shel Pesach. Would the people that refrain from Gebruks that live in Eretz Yisroel eat Gebruks on Sheviyi Shel Pesach?

Comment: "Do", not "Would", no?

Comment: I wish we did the same for Kitniyoth. :-(

Comment: Even though I gave my answer below, it would be nice to hear what someone in Israel actually does. Anyone from Israel here?

Answer (score 3):

Well the real question is why do they eat it on Achron Shel Pesach.

**EDITED**: It seems [Halachically Speaking](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol7Issue4.pdf) (thanks [SimchasTorah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/87/simchastorah)) brings 3 possible reasons for the minhag. It appears that all three apply in Israel the same way they apply here.

> The custom is to be lenient with gebrokts on the last day of Pesach. Some explain that we signify that those who eat gebrokts the entire Yom Tov are not doing anything wrong. Others explain that one should have Simchas Yom Tov. Others say that the various dietary customs preclude any possibility of people mingling. We want to accomplish this at least on the last day of Pesach, so we all brok. This was the custom of the Chofetz Chaim zt”l.

[I originally assumed that the reason is because the last day is only a safek, which would not apply in Israel]

Comment: yydl why dont you make that a question

Comment: @SimchasTorah because I'm pretty sure I know why... But you can...

Comment: The custom is to be lenient with gebrokts on the last day of Pesach.48 Some explain
that we signify that those who eat gebrokts the entire Yom Tov are not doing anything
wrong.49 Others explain that one should have Simchas Yom Tov.50 Others say that the
various dietary customs preclude any possibility of people mingling. We want to
accomplish this at least on the last day of Pesach, so we all brok.51 This was the custom
of the Chofetz Chaim zt”l

Comment: halachicly speaking

Comment: No source, but my understanding was it was to show that it's only a Humrah/Minhag.

Comment: Similar to 49 above.

Answer (score 1):

The [Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15952&st=&pgnum=44) mentions two reasons for permitting Gebroks on the last day:

1. To differentiate between Deoraysa to DeRabbanan - Not applicable in Israel as the last day is Deoraysa just as well.
2. Because the last day of Pesach is after a whole week of Sfiras Haomer ("doing  avoda on the Sefira of Chesed"), we are more "ready" to eat (and "handle") the more "chametzlike" food of Matza Shruya. This isn't applicable on the seventh day of Pesach (even in Israel) as it's still within that week.

Comment: Is differentiating between deoraita and derabanan a reason to or to not start eating gebrochts on the last day?

Comment: @DoubleAA start eating

Comment: Odd, I would have expected the opposite, given that Chazal were willing to let people say hundreds of what would be brachos levatalla to avoid distinguishing between the two days of Yom Tov ([Shabbos 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=23&format=pdf))